# Retag of two big tags with exactly the same meaning : function\method-overloading

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

[function-overloading](/questions/tagged/function-overloading) (123 questions)
[method-overloading](/questions/tagged/method-overloading)  (283 questions)

I believe they should be joined and one should be a synonym to the other.

Comment: Both tag wikis suck.

Comment: @RobertHarvey. Didn't you like _"For issues relating to overloading functions or methods."_ ? Very informative.

Comment: It's almost as good as ***Recursion*** -- *See Recursion.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey. Damn it, my browser crashed! That's wasn't funny!

Comment: Um, which one should win out though?

Comment: @casperOne. I don't know... function and method are synonyms, so it doesn't matter. I would chose the bigger tag ( `method-overloading` )